# htaccess expire header & compression

Tags: php, apache, compression, gzip, mod-expires

After long searching & test of my application I did add the following lines to my "htaccess" file, but when I test the website if it has compression on, it says "no" & also for expire headers, it doesn't seem to work. Please provide a fix

```
# 480 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 2 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# 2 HOURS
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<Files .htaccess>

    Order Allow,Deny

    Deny from all

</Files>
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```